# GCP Cloud Functions helpers

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-source-repos

Assume we're deploying GCP Cloud Functions from a GitHub repo (mirrored via GCP Source Repositories). Is it possible to set up shared code that can be accessed by both functions below? (e.g. via `helpers.py`).

```
helpers.py
function_one/
├── main.py
function_two/
├── main.py
```

Comment: If you are using Linux, create a file link so that a link to helpers.py is in both directories (function_one and function_two).

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly, since each function is a separate entity. But you could move your helpers.py to its own repository, then import the repository within each individual function.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you make a library out of your helpers (like any other libs in your requirements), then you import it as a dependency of function1 or function2.

Cloud Functions will get all your functions dependencies before running the function1.